# Insight into jQuery's .find()? (Unexpected results)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a "category tree" with several select boxes. When you choose a category for an item to be in, it loads the children categories and displays them in the next select box.

On `.submit()` for the form, I have it delete the first `.category` from the DOM. Once the last one is left, it gives the `name` attribute to the last `.category`.

The twist comes when there are multiple item forms on a page. What I have done is iterate over the `.item`s with jQuery's `.each()` and then from there, use jQuery's `.find()` to find the categories within an item.

**The While loop that I am using creates a endless loop.** I have used `console.log()` to output my variables throughout the execution of the script, and I don't think `.find()` is returning what I think it is.

html:

```
<div class="item">
    ....
    <div class="category"></div>
    <div class="category"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#transaction-form').submit(function(){
    $('.item').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).index();
        var category = $(this).find('.category');
        while (category.length > 1){
            $($(category)[0]).parent().remove();
        }
        $(category[0]).attr('name', 'form-' + index.toString() + '-category');
    });
});
```

Calling `category.length` in the while statement returns 2, as it should. I don't think the returned value of `.find()` is a jQuery object.

Comment: `category` is a jQuery object, not a live list of nodes. Removing the node from the DOM does not remove it from your jquery object. So its length never changes, and you're stuck in the loop.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I completely over looked that. Thank you, just have to recalculate the categories

Comment: 3 jQuery objects at play here... `$($(category)[0])` Seriously, just do `category.eq(0).parent().remove()`, or since it seems you want to remove all but the last, get rid of the `while` and do `category.slice(0,-1).remove()`

Comment: +1 for the more readable/functional/speedy refactor :)

Comment: I was messing with a fiddle, but it already got answered. Anyway, here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfg5r/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#transaction-form').submit(function(){
    var x = $('.item').has('.category');
    x.not(x.last()).remove();
    });
});
```

References

[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

[.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Woah. Thank you. `.has()`, is great. It sounds like it would be a boolean, but it really just "extends" your current jquery selector in a way. Totally cool!

Answer (score 1):

Removing your category parent entries doesn't actually remove it from the Jquery object. So you got an infinite loop because your length never actually changes...